# how to use BingMapsTask without search parameter

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xaml

I would like to load up the BingMapsTask on a users request via a button click event, although I do not want to set a particular search parameter for the Task. I really just want the user to be able to use the built in functions such as viewing traffic and Bing Scout in their current location (found without using the Center property). Is this possible, because as far as I can tell I must include a search query with the task for it to work correctly. I've tried using an empty string for the search as well as leaving the search out completely, neither of which work. If this is not possible, how could I get the users current location and pass that to the search parameter? I've attempted to use geocoordinatewatcher to get the current latitude and longitude but I am unsure of how to pass these values to the search?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming you know how to define GeoCoordinateWatcher, and hence after intializing the GeoCoordinateWatcher use the following code to use the BingMapsTask in your button click event handler

```
if(watcher != null)
        {
            BingMapsTask bing = new BingMapsTask();
            bing.Center = new GeoCoordinate(watcher.Position.Location.Latitude, watcher.Position.Location.Longitude);
            bing.ZoomLevel = 12;
            bing.Show();
        }
```

here watcher is the `GeoCoordinateWatcher` object

Comment: Thanks, it seems that either a Center or a Search must be defined for BingMapsTask to work correctly, which answers my question. As for defining and initializing GeoCoordinateWatcher, I defined this in my fields sectin and initialized it in my constructor although there is no garuntee that the user will use this function in my app. Where would you recommend this be defined and initialized for maximum performance? I do not want the user to have to wait for the location to be initialized before seeing their location on the map, although I'm not sure of what best practices are for this situation?